# Como puedo evitar que se ejecute mi codigo cuando este va a fallar? PHP

Tags: php, laravel

no se si existe o se puede hacer lo que estoy pidiendo... Les explico mi problema... Tengo un sistema de transferencia de puntos... que ya esta en producción... ya lo he probado miles de veces y siempre me funciona... pero ya van 2 veces en que otros usuarios tuvieron un problema... por ejemplo el total de sus puntos quedo en cero.. o que transfirió sin descontar... el problema es que no puedo solucionar el error porque ni si quiera lo veo...
Entonces mi pregunta es.. se puede evitar ejecutar el código cuando va a funcionar mal? o ya es muy fantasioso eso

mi codigo

```
public function transferir(Request $request) {

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $monto_a_transferir = $request->monto;

    $puntos_acumulados = $request->punto_acumulado;

    $user_a_regalar = $request->cuenta;

    $user_a_transferir = DB::select("SELECT id FROM colaboradores WHERE id = '$request->cuenta'");

    $registros = DB::select('SELECT id, total_puntos_positivos from puntos where user_id ='. $user_id);

    $registro_a_sumar = DB::select("SELECT id, total_puntos_positivos from puntos where user_id ='$user_a_regalar' order by id desc limit 1");
    // var_dump($registro_a_sumar); die;

    $cantidad_registros = count($registros);

    $acumulado = 0;


    if (md5($request->pass) == Auth::user()->PASSWORD) { 

        if ($monto_a_transferir <= $puntos_acumulados) {

            if ($registro_a_sumar) {

                if ($monto_a_transferir > $acumulado) {

                    for ($i=0; $i < $cantidad_registros; $i++) {

                        if ($registros[$i]->total_puntos_positivos > 0) {

                            if ($acumulado ==  $monto_a_transferir) {
                                // var_dump('acumulado ya es igual al monto a transferir '.$acumulado);
                                // actualiza el registro del que regala
                                $punto = Punto::findOrFail($registros[$i]->id);
                                $punto->total_puntos_positivos = 0;
                                $punto->save();

                                // registra la transeferencia para el beneficiado
                                $monto_transferencia = $registro_a_sumar[0]->total_puntos_positivos + $acumulado;
                                $punto_a_registrar = Punto::findOrFail($registro_a_sumar[0]->id);
                                $punto_a_registrar->total_puntos_positivos = $monto_transferencia;
                                $punto_a_registrar->save();

                                // crear registro de transferencia
                                $regalo = new Regalo();
                                $regalo->puntos = $acumulado;
                                $regalo->user_regalo = $user_id;
                                $regalo->user_recibio = $user_a_regalar;
                                $regalo->save();

                                // var_dump('se regalo');
                                \Session::flash('success','La transferencia se realizo con exito');
                                break;
                                // este break en la puta vida lo borres o se vuelve a repetir el ciclo a pesar de que ya la transferencia ya se realizo.

                            }

                            if ($acumulado <  $monto_a_transferir) {
                                // actualiza el registro e iguala a 0
                                $acumulado = $acumulado + $registros[$i]->total_puntos_positivos;
                                $punto = Punto::findOrFail($registros[$i]->id);
                                $punto->total_puntos_positivos = 0;
                                $punto->save();

                                // var_dump('el acumulado quedo en '. $acumulado . ' y el monto a transferir es '. $monto_a_transferir);
                            }
                            if ($acumulado > $monto_a_transferir) {
                                // var_dump('el acumulado '. $acumulado . ' ya paso al monto a transferir '. $monto_a_transferir);

                                $vuelto = $acumulado - $monto_a_transferir;
                                // actualiza el registro
                                $punto = Punto::findOrFail($registros[$i]->id);
                                $punto->total_puntos_positivos = $vuelto;
                                $punto->save();

                                // registra la transeferencia
                                $monto_transferencia = $registro_a_sumar[0]->total_puntos_positivos + $monto_a_transferir;
                                $punto_a_registrar = Punto::findOrFail($registro_a_sumar[0]->id);
                                $punto_a_registrar->total_puntos_positivos = $monto_transferencia;
                                $punto_a_registrar->save();


                                 // crear registro de transferencia
                                $regalo = new Regalo();
                                $regalo->puntos = $monto_a_transferir;
                                $regalo->user_regalo = $user_id;
                                $regalo->user_recibio = $user_a_regalar;
                                $regalo->save();

                                \Session::flash('success','La transferencia se realizo con exito');
                                break;
                                // este break en la puta vida lo borres o se vuelve a repetir el ciclo a pesar de que ya la transferencia ya se realizo.
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    \Session::flash('warnning','Agregar un monto a transferir valido!');  
                }
            } else {
                \Session::flash('warnning','El numero de cuenta del destinatario no existe o no tiene un registro de puntos todavia');  
            }
        } else {
            \Session::flash('warnning','El monto a transferir es superior al credito disponible');
        }
    } else {
         \Session::flash('warnning','La contraseña introducida es incorrecta!');

    }
    return redirect('/transferencia');
}
```

El código en realidad es muy simple... tengo una columna que se llama total_puntos_positivos... La suma de todos esos registros da 
un total de puntos que tiene cada usuario... con el código lo que hago es descuento uno a uno los puntos de cada registro hasta que supere o sea igual al monto que quiere transferir... cuando voy descantando los puntos que tiene el usuario lo guardo en una variable llamada acumulado... no se si me explico bien.. cualquier ayuda, sugerencia o duda me avisan por favor.. gracias

Comment: te recomiendo leer: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php para el manejo de errores y excepciones para que logres debuggear mejor tu código.

Answer (score 1):

La primera recomendación que se te puede dar para hacer un seguimiento del flujo de datos y manejo de errores en tu pieza de código con problemas es modularizar tu código.

tienes muchas lineas de código y debes agrupar cada comportamiento y acción del código en una función, para así lograr que tu código se entienda y se pueda detectar el error más fácilmente o la fuente de error, asi que un pequeño code review.

revisando el código, puede que existan muchas fuentes de errores que no se estén capturando o controlando. para esto necesitas utilizar [TRY CATCH](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php)

Por ejemplo:

1) El FindOrFail:

> " permite recuperar un registro de un modelo a partir de su ID sin
>   necesidad de comprobar si existe. El resultado es que en caso de no
>   existir, el método findOrFail lanza una excepción
>   ModelNotFoundException. "

lo ideal para utilizar el FindOrFail es lo siguiente:

```
try {
            $punto = Punto::findOrFail($registros[$i]->id);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            abort(404);
    }
```

2) En tu código este lógica que realizas:

```
if ($acumulado <  $monto_a_transferir) {
          // actualiza el registro e iguala a 0
         $acumulado = $acumulado + $registros[$i]->total_puntos_positivos;
         $punto = Punto::findOrFail($registros[$i]->id);
         $punto->total_puntos_positivos = 0;
         $punto->save();

  }
   if ($acumulado > $monto_a_transferir) {

   }
```

`if ($acumulado > $monto_a_transferir)` Debería ser un `ELSE`, ya que el valor de acumulado "muta" en el bloque anterior, por lo cual puede que entre al primer `IF` y luego al if mencionado sin problema generando errores en los valores a registrar.

Para responder a tu pregunta concretamente, puedes cambiar tu manera de hacer `update` e `insert` en tu base de datos con   `DB::beginTransaction();` de la sección [transacciones](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions)

el siguiente ejemplo se obtiene de la pregunta del sitio en ingles [catching user exceptions and fatal errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906844/laravel-using-try-catch-with-dbtransaction) donde el BeginTransaction y Rollback realizan la funcion de concretar las consultas en caso exitoso o no concretar nada si existe alguna excepción.

```
try {
    DB::insert(...);
    DB::insert(...);
    DB::insert(...);

    DB::commit();
    // all good
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    // something went wrong
}
```

Comment: se que es mucho pedir.. pero podrias poner un ejemplo con mi codigo lo que segun a tu parecer falta mejorar? no entiendo como usar las transacciones que mencionas

Comment: fijate en la siguiente respuesta aprobada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231810/how-can-i-use-db-transaction-in-laravel para entender como  "usar las transacciones que mencionas ". 

el DB::commit(); realiza la acción de destruir, para tu caso puede ser el insert o el update.

acá tienes más ejemplos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772160/what-happens-to-a-laravel-db-transaction-if-an-exception-is-thrown

la idea es incluir tus instrucciones con save(), dentro del beginTransaction y luego  commit(), si falla el rollback dejara nulos los cambios.

Comment: si me estuve fijando... la verdad no me queda muy claro como hacer el update...  tampoco se si mi try catch lo debo poner desde el primer if o debo poner 3 try catch dentro de mi foreach

Comment: @HernanChaparro pon solo un try catch que encapsule todo el código. el begin tran debe encapsular tus save(). de los IF más interiores.